# Optimize SQL inner join on a 36 million row table with 3 columns

Tags: mysql, sql, join, optimization

We have a few of these types of tables with roughly 30 million ~ 80 million rows per table.
We are interested in running analysis on the table, but the queries take long time (queries takes over 10 minute) to execute. Can SQL guru spot any obvious optimization we could apply to fasten the query execution ?

URL contains information about sql schema, 
sample rows 
and the query we wanted to execute at the very bottom.
We've also added an index on `userid` but the query still takes a long time.
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=pn9Kyg2z
table created with innodb on mariadb. Server has 12G allocated to buffer pool

Comment: Your SQL scripts should be inlined into the question for posterity and ease of reading by others.

Comment: thanks. We tried both with and without subquery and the resulting runtime is 11 minutes and 5 minutes in MySQL.  We moved to PostgreSQL and the run time is 15 seconds with and without subquery on the same table. (sqldump and reload into postgres)

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of a simple example, I'll work from [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df86f/2).

Reduced schema:

```
CREATE TABLE visits(
  user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  minute_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  visit_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX visits_user_id_idx ON visits(user_id);
CREATE INDEX visits_minute_id_idx ON visits(minute_id);
CREATE INDEX visits_visit_id_idx ON visits(visit_id);
```

You're currently using a subquery, something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(v1.visit_id)
FROM visits v1
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM visits WHERE minute_id BETWEEN 100 AND 200) v2 ON v2.user_id = v1.user_id
WHERE v1.minute_id BETWEEN 600 AND 700;
```

You don't need that inline subquery with a temporary table -- it's causing the DB to churn up a whole bunch more data than it needs to, which is slowing things down.

The same logic could be achieved in a flat query:

```
SELECT COUNT(v1.visit_id)
FROM visits v1
INNER JOIN visits v2 ON v2.user_id = v1.user_id
WHERE v2.minute_id BETWEEN 100 AND 200
AND v1.minute_id BETWEEN 600 AND 700;
```

The fiddle link includes `EXPLAIN` results which demonstrate the DB engine will have a much easier time handling this, both because less temporary data is kept and because the required indexing is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Rutter's simplification.

This seems to be the query that you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(v1.visit_id)
FROM visits v1 INNER JOIN
     visits v2
     ON v2.user_id = v1.user_id
WHERE v2.minute_id BETWEEN 100 AND 200 AND v1.minute_id BETWEEN 600 AND 700;
```

This seems to be a count of the number of visits for users that had a visit in two time periods.

You can also express this as:

```
select sum(numvisit)
from (select user_id, count(*) as numvisit
      from visits v
      where v.minute_id BETWEEN 100 AND 200 or v.minute_id BETWEEN 600 AND 700
      group by user_id
      having sum(v.minute_id BETWEEN 100 AND 200) > 0 and
             sum(v.minute_id BETWEEN 600 AND 700) > 0
     ) uv;
```

If MySQL will use an index on `minute_id` for the `where` *and* the amount of data is not very large, then this might have better performance.

EDIT:

As Spencer very correctly points out, the second query gets the number of *visits* in the two time periods.  This seems useful.  It also seems useful to get the number of users with visits in the two time periods, which would be `count(*)` instead of `sum(numvisits)`.

The product of the number of visits in each period, per user, seems highly unlikely as a desired result.  But, if that is what you really want, then:

```
select sum(cnt1 * cnt2)
from (select user_id, count(*) as numvisit,
             sum(v.minute_id BETWEEN 100 AND 200) as cnt1,
             sum(v.minute_id BETWEEN 600 AND 700)
      from visits v
      where v.minute_id BETWEEN 100 AND 200 or v.minute_id BETWEEN 600 AND 700
      group by user_id
      having sum(v.minute_id BETWEEN 100 AND 200) > 0 and
             sum(v.minute_id BETWEEN 600 AND 700) > 0
     ) uv;
```

would be the query.  However, why would you want this particular value?

Comment: Gordon, I like the approach of the second query; getting those rows collapsed. The result from this is significantly different than the original query, which seems to be doing a semi-cross join between rows in the two time periods. (I suspect that may not have been the intent, but that is what it's doing.) To get the same result as the original query, we could replace `count(*)` with the product of the two `sum()` expressions in the `having` clause.  I also like the BETWEEN (in this case) if `minuteid` is integer.  `> 23790480` is the same as `>= (23790480+1)`.

Comment: @spencer7593 . . . You are totally correct.  I just find the desired count to be highly unlikely as a useful result.  I would expect the total number of users with visits in the two times to be the most useful value (and this would be `count(*)`).  Then, the total number of visits (which this calculates).  The product per user seems unlikely to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

EXPLAIN output from MariaDB does not show derived table, so scratch that part. (Older versions of MySQL *always* create a derived table for inline views.) So, skip the bit about inline view queries and derived tables...

And look at the recommendations for adding multicolumn indexes (and dropping the singleton column indexes).

---

<strike>Likely, your spending most of the time scanning the derived table; or, materializing the derived table (and creating indexes on it, if your version of MariaDB indexes derived tables.)</strike>

I'm not understanding why you need an inline view.

I think this will produce the same resultset:

```
 SELECT COUNT(1)
   FROM td222_visits_ppp v
   JOIN td222_visits_ppp l
     ON l.userid = v.userid
    AND l.minuteid >= 23704140
    AND l.minuteid <= 23790480
  WHERE p.minuteid  > 23790480
    AND p.minuteid <= 23878320
```

(Are you sure the query is getting the number you want... every row for a particular userid in a particular time period cross joined to every row for that same userid in a different time period?)

The indexes on the individual columns aren't going to be too much help for this query. The most appropriate index for this query is going to be:

```
... ON td222_visits_ppp (user_id, minuteid)
```

(NOTE: This makes the index on the `user_id` column redundant, that is, any query currently using the existing index on `user_id` could make use of this new index, which has `user_id` as the leading column.)

I'd be interested in the `EXPLAIN` from this query, after the new index is created.

(We'd like to see a range scan operation being performed on `v`, using the full key length of 12, and `Using index` in the 'Extra' column. On `p`, we're likely to see a range scan operation of the index on `minuteid`.)

If we had another index

```
... ON td222_visits_ppp (minuteid, userid)
```

That would make the index on just minuteid redundant, and the query could be satisfied from the index as well (without no need to visit the underlying data page to lookup the `userid`.)

---

**EDIT**

I just looked at the EXPLAIN output from MariaDB... and we're not seeing a "derived table" there, so scratch that bit of my answer about the time spent materializing and scanning or indexing a derived table. (Older versions of MySQL that we're familiar do that for inline view queries.)

I stand on my recommendation for adding multicolumn indexes (replacing the singleton column indexes).